# What is the C syntax/operator for adding matrixes?

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

I am relatively new to C programming and am stuck with a problem. I am trying to create a 'Transpose function' that will take a matrix_a and transpose and store it as matrix_b. The end goal is to call this function in an equation later on.
For example: Result_Matrix = Matrix_A + Transpose_Matrix_A + Matrix B*MatrixA
Ideally I would just call the Transpose function in the equation, not sure if that is even possible in C but that's my thought process.

This is what I have got so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4
  
// This function stores transpose of A[][] in B[][]
void transpose(int A[][N], int B[][N])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            B[i][j] = A[j][i];
}
  
int main()
// Specify matrix
{
    int A[N][N] = { {1, 1, 1, 1},
                    {2, 2, 2, 2},
                    {3, 3, 3, 3},
                    {4, 4, 4, 4}};
  
    int B[N][N], i, j;
  
    transpose(A, B);
  
   //  printf("Result matrix is \n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%d ", B[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

This transposes a matrix but it does not store the new matrix.
Edit 1: I know the transpose function works but I am not sure how to call it in an equation:
`New_Matrix = Matrix_A + Transpose_Function(Matrix_A)`
^I want to call the function I created in an equation like so.

Comment: *"it does not store the new matrix*". What do you mean by that? Is the result not stored in the `B` matrix? Can you please give the exact expected result vs actual result? (Also: why do you show the same code repeated multiple times?).

Comment: Sorry I must've pasted it too many times, I have fixed it now. So when I run the code I get the output                                                                                                        1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4 
1 2 3 4                                                                                                                       But I want it saved in the form a matrix like how I initialized A[N][N] so I can do further matrix operations on it. So the exact expected result would be the new transposed matrix stored in C[N][N].

Comment: The end end goal of this whole thing would be to just call the transpose function in an equation that consists of matrix multiplication, addition, transpose. Simply I want to say something like Matrix D = Transpose_function(MatrixA) + Matrix A. I'm not really sure how to create this Transpose_function that I can call in my equations

Comment: That still doesn't make sense. How is `B[N][N]` not already what you describe  as `C[N][N]`? But for the more general end goal you cannot just use `+`/`*` operators on any matrix. C can't do that. You will have to call functions for that.

Comment: So if I have the following equation: Matrix_A + Matrix_A_Transpose, how would I input my Transpose function in the equation?

Comment: Works for me. I don't see the problem. https://ideone.com/dKDE5N

Comment: `transpose(A, B); matrix_add(A, B, C);` with final result in `C`.

Comment: @kaylum Let's turn that into an answer. Will you?

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for turning that into an answer. It looks good.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks for confirming my assumption that you would not mind. Otherwise I would have deleted my answer (and probably upvoted yours, I only want this out of the list of unanswered questions).

Answer (score 1):

As kaylum explained, C does not offer the kind of operator use which you are imagining.
Even if your functions would return something (most likely a pointer to the result matrix), adding it with `+` would not be what you need.
So it is necessary to call functions, e.g. as kaylum proposed:

> `transpose(A, B); matrix_add(A, B, C);` with final result in C

After the call to `transpose()` the transposed matrix is found in `B`, which has to be a suitably sized array (be careful with your code and non-square matrixes by the way). Then, without an operator like `+` being used, that `B` is used as parameter to a function `matrix_add()`, which does not exist in your shown code, but structurally is similar to the one you created. Again, `C` contains the final result and must be a suitably sized array with scope and life-time beyond that second function (like the `B` you created).